# What is reaction between isopropyl alcohol and acetone?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, alcohols

What would be the probable reaction between acetone, $\ce{(CH3)2CO}$, and isopropyl alcohol, $\ce{CH3CHOHCH3}$, at room temperature without any catalyst in different concentrations?

Comment: There would be none.

Comment: As Ivan already said there would be no reaction. You might as well have any ketone with any alcohol - the only thing that could conceivably happen would be hemiacetal/acetal formation but that certainly needs acid catalysis.

Comment: Unless you excite the acetone (UV irradiation), I'd suppose that nothing happens.

Comment: If something happened, you might be in real trouble washing out a reaction vessel with isopropanol as solvent at the end of the day...

Comment: with higher temperature , i think oxygen atom of hydroxide group give her lone pair to ketonic group of acetone with 1,3 proton shift give isopropyl isopropanol ether

Answer (score 4):

I've used acetone/ipa mix to flush chromatography columns. There is no reaction between them without another reagent present

Answer (score 2):

I mix rubbing alcohol and acetone together to clean flux off of stained glass that I have soldered. Nothing happens when you mix them.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously these liquids do not react with each other.  But they can be interconverted.  Isopropanol can be converted to acetone simply by heating over a copper catalyst (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isopropyl_alcohol).  And as many readers know, sodium borohydride or lithium aluminum hydride reduces acetone to isopropanol (https://www.chemguide.co.uk/organicprops/carbonyls/reduction.html).